# Copy files FromPath to folders using text in the file name as the variable to determine ToPath location

Tags: excel, vba

I want to copy pdf files in one master folder to several other locations.

There is a segment of this macro where the files need to be copied to three different folders according to the state abbreviations in the file name.

- Files containing AZ, CA, CO, and NM go in the "Main" folder.
- Files containing FL go in the "FL" folder
- All other state abbreviations go in the "Secondary" folder.

How do I list multiple state abbreviation at once and move those files.

```
Sub Copy_Certain_Files_In_Folder()

    Dim FSO As Object
    Dim FromPath As String
    Dim ToPath As String
    Dim FileName As String

    FromPath = "C:\Users\Name\Desktop\Master File"  '<< Change
    ToPath = "C:\Users\Name\Desktop\SharePoint\Main"    '<< Change

    FileName = "DOC-AZ*" Or "DOC-CA*" Or "DOC-CO*" Or "DOC-NM*"

    If Right(FromPath, 1) <> "\" Then
        FromPath = FromPath & "\"
    End If

    Set FSO = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")

    If FSO.FolderExists(FromPath) = False Then
        MsgBox FromPath & " doesn't exist"
        Exit Sub
        End If

    If FSO.FolderExists(ToPath) = False Then
        MsgBox ToPath & " doesn't exist"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    FSO.CopyFile Source:=FromPath & FileName, Destination:=ToPath

    MsgBox "You can find the files from " & FromPath & " in " & ToPath

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can use wildcard copy in your case. If you first copy FL, AZ, CA, CO and MN to their location, they will be copied once again, since you can't make a negative wildcard for all the rest. Differently put - FL will be part of all the rest, too. Had you moved it instead, it would have worked.
Now, you can't build that kind of wildcards with FSO. Instead you will have to process them one at a time, like this (slightly simplified):

```
Dim FSO As Object
Dim FromPath As String
Dim ToPath As String
Dim FileName As String

FromPath = "C:\Users\Name\Desktop\Master File"
Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

For Each File In FSO.GetFolder(FromPath).Files

    Select Case Mid(File.Name, 5, 2)
        Case "FL"
            ToPath = "FL"
        Case "AZ", "CA", "CO", "NM"
            ToPath = "Main"
        Case Else
            ToPath = "Secondary"
    End Select
    ToPath = "C:\Users\Name\Desktop\SharePoint\" & ToPath

    FSO.CopyFile FromPath & "\" & File.Name, ToPath
Next
```

The `Select Case` statement picks letter 5-6 and checks. It might be too specific for your case, but I think you get the point.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I see what you are saying. When I run this code I am getting Run-time error '53': File not found.

Comment: did you change the path names?

Comment: I have updated the code above. The second to last line is now a bit better

Comment: Thank you for the update. From what I can tell it looks like this should work. Now I am getting a Runtime error '70': Permission Denied. I wasn't getting this error when the macro was copying over one file at a time, so not sure why that's happening. Thanks

Comment: From what I have read, this is occurring because of a Windows security update from 2017. Windows recommends changing the code to use Windows API CoCreateGuid instead of “CreateObject

Comment: It's better if you add a reference to it. Have a look here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/186118/how-to-use-filesystemobject-with-visual-basic